# Every compact hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Show that every compact hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is orientable. HINT: Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem.

This is an exercise from Guillemin and Pollack. So hypersurface means smooth hypersurface. Jordan's Theorem says that if $S$ is some hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus S$ has two connected components (and their common boundary is $S$).

But I don't really see how this implies that $S$ is orientable. Would anyone give me some help?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not useless to spell out what "G&P" is...

Comment: The boundary of an orientable manifold is orientable.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thank you, but are you saying that the connected components are orientable smooth manifolds?

Comment: An open submanifold of an orientable manifold is orientable, and a manifold with boundary is orientable iff its interior is. (You should probably refresh your background on orientability! ;-) )

Comment: thank you for your time, Mariano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in S$, and $u$ a vector of $T_xR^n$ orthogonal to $T_xS$, you can suppose that $\|u\|=1$ ( for the Euclidean norm) and $u$ points towards the component $U_1$ of $R^n-S$. This defines uniquely $u$ and you obtain a non trivial vector field $X(x)=u$. $i_X\omega$ restricted to $S$ is a volume form, where $\omega$ is the canonical volume form of $R^n$.