# Differential Geometry: Smooth Charts from $\Bbb R^2$ to the Klein Bottle

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

I am trying to show that $\Bbb R^2$ induces a smooth structure on the Klein Bottle $K$ = $\Bbb R^2$/~, where the equivalence relation is: $\Bbb R^2$: ($x_1$, $x_2$) ∼ ($x_1 + n_1, 1 − x_2 + n_2$), for some ($n_1, n_2$) ∈ $\Bbb Z^2$.

(I believe this means that there exists a diffeomorphism from the Klein bottle to $\Bbb R^2$ modulo this particular equivalence relation).

The Goal (or my understanding of it anyway): Find charts that take an open sets in $\Bbb R^2$ to sets in the Klein Bottle's equivalence relation. This means, find $P_i: U_{open}$ $\subset$ $\Bbb R^2$ $\to$ $V \subset K$ = $\Bbb R^2$/~. Then, all we have to do is show that this charts follow the properties of 'smoothness':

$\quad$(i) each chart $P_i$ is injective,

$\quad$(ii) if ($V_\alpha \cap V_\beta) \neq \emptyset$ then $P^{-1}_\alpha(V_\alpha \cap V_\beta)$ and $P^{-1}_\beta(V_\alpha \cap V_\beta)$ are open in $\Bbb R^2$ and there exists a diffeomorphism from $V_\alpha \cap V_\beta$ to $P^{-1}_\beta(V_\alpha \cap V_\beta)$ given by $P^{-1}_\beta \circ P_\alpha$,

$\quad$(iii) $\cup_i  P_i (U_i)= K$ which means the union of all the charts cover the whole manifold.

Finding the Charts: 
Using this equivalence relation, I would think the charts should look somewhat like so: $P_i: (x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$ $\to$ ($x_1 + n_1, 1 − x_2 + n_2$) such that $(n_1, n_2) \in \Bbb Z^2$.

My Question: I am still having trouble figuring out exactly what the charts should be and how many I will need to cover the whole manifold.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is that compatible with the fact that every smooth hypersurface is orientable (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783120/every-compact-hypersurface-in-mathbbrn-is-orientable)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using open balls in the plane of radius $1/2$ as your domain for the functions $P_i$.  Since every point in the Klein bottle has a representative in the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, it will suffice to map the centers of these balls to $(0,0)$, $(1/2,0)$, $(0,1/2)$, and $(1/2,(1,2)$.  (Try drawing these four open balls and then take into account that the parts of the ball which land outside this square still cover points of the Klein bottle.  One useful way to think about this is the model where opposite sides are identified, although the top and bottom sides are identified with a flip of the edge.)  Once you are convinced these balls are mapped by homeomorphisms, you need to study what happens to points which lie in two balls.  This is where some work will need to be done.

There are other ways to approach this problem, of course.  The one which is close to this is when one has a nice (discrete) group action on a space you already know has a smooth structure and the group acts by diffeomorphisms.  In this context, the Klein bottle admits a smooth structure because there is a group acting by (sometimes orientation reversing) affine maps on the plane and the Klein bottle is the resulting quotient object (called the orbit space).

Comment: So, in this case, the charts would be: P: {(x1, x2) | ((x1-h)^2 + (x2-k)^2) <= 1/4} --> (x1+n1, 1-x2+n2) where (n1, n2) in Z^2 and (h,k) are the centers of the circles (0,0), (0,1/2), (1/2, 0) and (1/2, 1/2)? Now, all I have to do is show that these maps are 'smooth'? Thank you.

Comment: You will want to define the charts using piecewise linear functions.  Once you check that they are continuous, you need to write down the composite functions for each pair of charts.  The chart centered at $(0,0)$ is the most challenging.  Try the others first and save that for last.  The computations are a little tedious.  But after you've done this once, you'll appreciate better what Mariano is saying in his answer.  If you haven't already done so, write down the details for the torus first, as this is a simpler situation.

Answer (score 0):

*A suggestion:* It is easier to forget as many specific details of your situation and prove the following more general statement:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $N$ be a topological space and let $p:M\to N$ be a covering. Then $N$ is a smooth manifold in a canonical way in such a way that the map $p$ is locally a diffeomorphism.

Comment: This statement seems kind of obvious, but I couldn't prove it. It is straightforward to show that the covering space of a smooth manifold is a smooth manifold, but the other way around, when I tried to define charts on $N$ using charts of $N$ I ran into problems with choosing the right inverse of $p$. And on the wikipedia page on coverings I found a passage saying that in this setting $N$ may turn out to be non-Hausdorff, which makes me think that this is not as trivial a statement as it seems. Can you elaborate on the proof of this general statement, please?

Comment: @SergeyGuminov, I am pretty sure I was not considering the possibility of N being non-Hausdorff here when I wrote this, but this was in the context of the question in which you do know the base of the covering is a manifold! I'd therefore say that it is safe to assume in the statement that both spaces are Hausdorff.